# Is there a way in airflow where a Daily DAG is dependent on weekly (on weekends) DAG?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, data-pipeline

I have these Dags DAG_A (runs daily) , DAG_B (runs mon-fri) and DAG_C (runs on sat and sun) where DAG_A is dependent on both DAG_B and DAG_C.
I tried setting the dependencies using **External Task Sensor** but everytime my scheduler stops running and any of Dags aren't succeeding

Comment: Hi Lalitha and welcome to StackOverflow! From your description it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is. Please consider reading up on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use TriggerDagRunOperator for calling one DAG from another.

The details can be found in operator TriggerDagRunOperator Airflow documentation.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.dagrun_operator.TriggerDagRunOperator

call DAG_A from DAG_B and DAG_C when they finish the run.